# Whether to to keep or remove a comma before an adverbial participle: ", исходя из названия"

Tags: пунктуация

> Не огорчайтесь, не все так плохо, как кажется поначалу или **исходя из названия**.
>
> [or]: Не огорчайтесь, не все так плохо, как кажется поначалу или, **исходя из названия**.

Normally, an adverbial participle is preceded by a comma: "как кажется, исходя из названия". But what about when you have a *parallel* structure like this?

> как кажется поначалу [или] как кажется, исходя из названия

Do you keep a comma or drop it in a *combined* phrasing?

Answer (score 6):

I'd remove a comma here. `Исходя из` is not an adverbial participle but it is a preposition. And it isn't separated by commas if it is a part of a complex predicate and/or is closely related to it by the sense.

[Details (in Russian)](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_248).

---

*In contrast, here is a comma:*

> Мне показалось, исходя из названия, что ...

Comment: _Мне показалось, исходя_ is not that great an example!